# What is the correct encoding for PS1 files

Tags: powershell, character-encoding

I am doing some text stream processing on a series of PS1 & PSM1 files, and I ran into some issues with smart quotes and em-dashes (never, NEVER, cut and paste code from MS Scripting Guy blog). I figured the issue was encoding so I looked, and I have files of both ASCII & UTF8, but of course both have issues with my funky text. So I have done some replacements, and I have that working, but I wonder if I shouldn't also standardize on one encoding, and if so, which one?

Comment: PowerShell scripts should run fine regardless of whether the file is encoded as ASCII (ANSI, technically), UTF-8, or UTF-16. The problem was most likely due to some funky characters copy/pasted from your source. *Always* clean up code you copy from somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah, lesson learned the hard way! ;) And if there is no argument for any particular encoding I'll just force all of them to UTF8, if only for consistency sake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question but you may find it useful nonetheless, I have a tool I wrote to handle PS and SQL scripts but quickly found people were pasting from their emails which screwed a ton of stuff. I had to implement this to correct it all, and it should get everything:

```
if ($code.IndexOf([Char]0x2013) -gt -1) { $code = $code.Replace(([Char]0x2013).ToString(), "--") }   # en dash
if ($code.IndexOf([Char]0x2014) -gt -1) { $code = $code.Replace(([Char]0x2014).ToString(), "-") }    # em dash
if ($code.IndexOf([Char]0x2015) -gt -1) { $code = $code.Replace(([Char]0x2015).ToString(), "-") }    # horizontal bar
if ($code.IndexOf([Char]0x2017) -gt -1) { $code = $code.Replace(([Char]0x2017).ToString(), "_") }    # double low line
if ($code.IndexOf([Char]0x2018) -gt -1) { $code = $code.Replace(([Char]0x2018).ToString(), "`'") }   # left single quotation mark
if ($code.IndexOf([Char]0x2019) -gt -1) { $code = $code.Replace(([Char]0x2019).ToString(), "`'") }   # right single quotation mark
if ($code.IndexOf([Char]0x201a) -gt -1) { $code = $code.Replace(([Char]0x201a).ToString(), ",") }    # single low-9 quotation mark
if ($code.IndexOf([Char]0x201b) -gt -1) { $code = $code.Replace(([Char]0x201b).ToString(), "`'") }   # single high-reversed-9 quotation mark
if ($code.IndexOf([Char]0x201c) -gt -1) { $code = $code.Replace(([Char]0x201c).ToString(), "`"") }   # left double quotation mark
if ($code.IndexOf([Char]0x201d) -gt -1) { $code = $code.Replace(([Char]0x201d).ToString(), "`"") }   # right double quotation mark
if ($code.IndexOf([Char]0x201e) -gt -1) { $code = $code.Replace(([Char]0x201e).ToString(), "`"") }   # double low-9 quotation mark
if ($code.IndexOf([Char]0x2026) -gt -1) { $code = $code.Replace(([Char]0x2026).ToString(), "...") }  # horizontal ellipsis
if ($code.IndexOf([Char]0x2032) -gt -1) { $code = $code.Replace(([Char]0x2032).ToString(), "`"") }   # prime
if ($code.IndexOf([Char]0x2033) -gt -1) { $code = $code.Replace(([Char]0x2033).ToString(), "`"") }   # double prime
if ($code.IndexOf([Char]0x0009) -gt -1) { $code = $code.Replace(([Char]0x0009).ToString(), "    ") } # tab
```

Answer (score 6):

Since I just ran into this while troubleshooting encoding problems: I had some PS1 files encoded as UTF-8 and the powershell interpreter choked on some constant strings containing German umlaut characters ("äÄöÖüÜß"). Got an 'unexpected token' error (running PS 5.1 on Windows Server 2016). This particular problem vanished after changing the encoding of the PS1 file to UTF-8-BOM.

Comment: This fixed it for me: re-saving the file with the BOM allowed the script to run on a non-English system.

Answer (score 1):

PS1 Files historically used Windows-1252 as the fallback encoding.  If a BOM was present (either for UTF-8 or for UTF-16), it would be used instead.

[With Powershell 6](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/issues/71), the default encoding changes to UTF-8.

To make sure ps1 files work correctly on old and new versions, save them as UTF-8 with BOM.  This advice can be found in [about_Character_Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_character_encoding)